# How do I prevent insiders from accessing data or secrets encrypted with Cloud KMS?

Tags: google-cloud-kms

Is encrypting data with Cloud KMS sufficient to prevent my organization’s employees from accessing encrypted data? What best practices are there to avoid unnecessary exposure?

Answer (score 1):

Resources in Cloud KMS are Google Cloud Platform resources for which access can be managed using IAM, and access audited using Cloud Audit Logging. You should set permissions that will limit the use of encryption keys to only those individuals who should have access.

You can apply the principle of separation of duties - the individual who manages encryption keys should not be the same individual who accesses what those keys protect, such as secrets. Practically, you should give one person key administration rights, like key rotation, etc. (IAM role: Cloud KMS Admin); and another person key use rights, like to encrypt/ decrypt to access data (IAM role: Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter).

For further discussion on separation of duties in Cloud KMS: https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/separation-of-duties

To give a user the ability to manage a key with role Cloud KMS Admin, using gcloud run:

```
gcloud beta kms cryptokeys add-iam-policy-binding \
    CRYPTOKEY_NAME --location LOCATION --keyring KEYRING_NAME \
    --member user:MY-USER@gmail.com \
    --role roles/cloudkms.admin
```

To give a service account the ability to encrypt and decrypt using  a key with role Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter, using gcloud run:

```
gcloud beta kms cryptokeys add-iam-policy-binding \
    CRYPTOKEY_NAME --location LOCATION --keyring KEYRING_NAME \
    --member serviceAccount:MY-SERVICE_ACCOUNT@MY-PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter
```